# Is the class of all sets unique?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

I'm wondering wether the class $C$ defined by:
$$x\in C\Leftrightarrow x\subseteq C\quad\quad (1)$$
Is unique. Its existence is ensured by the following argument:

Let $U$ be the class of all sets, and $x\in U$ a set in it. Since $U$ contains all sets, then it must contain $\{x\}$, and so:
$$x\subseteq\{x\}\in U\Rightarrow x\subseteq U$$

Likewise, if $x\subseteq U$ is a set, it is, by definition, a member of $U$ ($U$ is non-empty).

So the class of all sets fits the definition of (1). My question is, is $U$ the only set that fits this description? By the axiom of extensionality we know $U$ is unique iff for every class $C$ that satisfies (1), we have that:
$$x\in C \Rightarrow x\in U$$
... But here i got stuck, since i don't know how to show this property for $C$, nor construct $C≠U$ that satisfies (1).
Any ideas?

Comment: Look up $\in$-induction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon-induction

Comment: What theory are you working with?

Comment: @AsafKaragila honestly, i'm not sure. I'm trying to prove the whole thing in NBG... but my main goal is to work in whatever theory can solve the *uniqueness* problem of the class $C$ (this is, proving $C$ to be unique or non-unique)

Comment: $\text{WF}\subseteq C$ because if $\text{WF}\setminus C\ne\emptyset$, let $x\in\text{WF}\setminus C$ be an element of least rank.  Then all members of $x$ are in $C$, so $x\subseteq C$ and therefore $x\in C$ - a contradiction.  If you assume regularity then $\text{WF}=U$.

Comment: BTW, Jech in "Axiom of Choice" defines the weaker property "almost universal" to mean a class $C$ such that if $x\subseteq C$, there is a $y\in C$ such that $x\subseteq y$.  In Theorem 3.2 in said book he shows that a class $M$ that is transitive, almost universal and closed under Gödel operations is a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$.